# Merge vs left join to insert missing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to bring in data from table a into table b every day.

Both tables have same schema.

I can either use MERGE (WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT) or I can do an INSERT of the result obtained by doing a left join of table a and table b on id where b.id is null.

Are these both approaches effectively the same?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is not the same. `NOT EXISTS` might be, and is usually better for performance anyway. Differences are very minor between that and `MERGE`, firstly that `MERGE` allows an `OUTPUT` clause from other tables, and allows multiple `DEFAULT` rows. But it also has more bugs, and higher compilation time.

Comment: Can you tell me why left join and is null is not same please

Comment: `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` although it has the same end result, does not look at all the same to the optimizer. There is currently no logic in the optimizer to transforms it into an anti-join, and it can mess up the cardinality estimates, and more importantly also, the uniqueness guarantees of the previous tables and joins. You may also find [this article](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/02/the-halloween-problem-part-3.html) by @PaulWhite useful, on the better optimizations available to `MERGE` in the case of hole-filling `NOT EXISTS` (self-anti-join)